# Optimize SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

i've 5 dropDowns from which user can select values to fetch data from table. Values of dropdowns are distinct values coming from different columns of the table. Each dropdowns also have an option "ALL". i'm storing user selections in 5 variables i.e variablename , variablename1 and so on... by Default is dropdown value will be ALL...

Currently i'm using 32 different queries with if and else-if conditions to fetch data .. i.e

```
if($variablename=="ALL" && $variablename2=="ALL" && $variablename5=="ALL" && $variablename6=="ALL" && $variablename7=="ALL")
{ $query="SELECT * FROM table ....}


  else if($variablename!="ALL" && $variablename2!="ALL" && $variablename5!="ALL" && $variablename6!="ALL" && $variablename7!="ALL")
        { $query= "SELECT * FROM table WHERE   abc = '$variablename' and bcd = '$variablename1' and cde= '$variablename2'
    and def= '$variablename4' and efg= '$variablename4' ; ...}
```

NOTE that !=ALL means that user have select some value from dropDown except ALL option.

In this way i've to make 32 different queries. how can i make more optimize query to get rid of making 32 different queries ? i hope you get my question ..

Comment: do some dynamic query builder. In my project i have done this one. 

    Step1 : have the table schema in XML 
    step2 : DO backtrak to frame query 

Or 

Simplest way : 

    Step1 : Have select and where class as a text template "select  from Table where"
    Step2 : do some string formatting to frame the query using selected fields.

Comment: Which server mysql or sqlserver?

Comment: Thot so cuz tagged as such. Hopefully you solve the dynamic builder as you could be at 128 procs soon!

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table";
$conditions = Array();
if ($variablename !== "ALL") {
  $conditions[] = "abc = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($variablename) . "'";
}
if ($variablename2 !== "ALL") {
  $conditions[] = "bcd = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($variablename2) . "'";
}
// ...
if ($conditions) {
  $query .= "WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $conditions);
}
```

Beware [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)! Also, it would be much nicer if you had an array, and not five different variables.